# Should I use a completion handler here? If so, how best to do it?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, completionhandler

I have a bug in my application that I just found, in this method:

```
private func createNotifications(dateComponents: DateComponents) {

    switch (recurrence) {
    case .today:
        createNotification(for: dateComponents)
    case .tomorrow:
        createNotification(for: day(after: dateComponents))
    case .daily:
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.getPendingNotificationRequests { (notifications) in
            var numberOfCreatableNotifications = 64 - notifications.count
            var numberOfCreatedNotifications = 0
            var currentDay: DateComponents? = dateComponents
            while numberOfCreatableNotifications > 0
                    && numberOfCreatedNotifications < self.NUMBER_OF_ALLOWED_NOTIFICATIONS_CREATED_AT_ONE_TIME {
                self.createNotification(for: currentDay)
                currentDay = self.day(after: currentDay)
                numberOfCreatableNotifications -= 1
                numberOfCreatedNotifications += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create an alarm with a certain recurrence option (today, tomorrow, or daily) and the daily case wasn't working. The code above is in Alarm.swift. When an alarm is created it's passed back to the main view controller for saving in Core Data. I realized that the notifications aren't being saved in Core Data because they aren't created by the time the alarm is saved in Core Data. There's this closure center.getPendingNotificationRequests() that apparently takes some time before it returns and runs the completion handler.

I'm using the getPendingNotificationRequests() method because I'm trying to determine how many notifications I have left that I can create (max of 64).

Here's my question: Should I continue to use this async method and just do some saving in Core Data during the completion handler? Or should the code for saving stay in the main view controller and I just stop using this async method, because I don't need it for some reason?

Thanks

BTW, Here's most of the code from my AlarmTableViewController file, the main VC in my application:

```
//MARK: Public properties
var alarms = [AlarmMO]()
let ALARM_CELL_IDENTIFIER = "AlarmTableViewCell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    requestUserNotificationsPermissionsIfNeeded()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    loadAlarms()

    for alarm in self.alarms {
        os_log("There are %d notifications for alarm %d", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug, alarm.notificationUuids.count, alarm.alarmNumber)
    }
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.alarms.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ALARM_CELL_IDENTIFIER, for: indexPath) as? AlarmTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of AlarmTableViewCell.")
    }

    guard let alarmMO = self.alarms[safe: indexPath.row] else {
        os_log("Could not unwrap alarm for indexPath in AlarmTableViewController.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .default)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        return AlarmTableViewCell()
    }
    let alarmNumber = alarmMO.value(forKey: "alarmNumber") as! Int
    let beginTime = alarmMO.value(forKey: "startTimeInterval") as! Double
    let endTime = alarmMO.value(forKey: "endTimeInterval") as! Double
    cell.alarmNumberLabel.text = "Alarm " + String(alarmNumber)

    let beginTimeHour = Alarm.extractHourFromTimeDouble(alarmTimeDouble: beginTime)
    let beginTimeMinute = Alarm.extractMinuteFromTimeDouble(alarmTimeDouble: beginTime)
    cell.beginTimeLabel.text = formatTime(hour: beginTimeHour, minute: beginTimeMinute)

    let endTimeHour = Alarm.extractHourFromTimeDouble(alarmTimeDouble: endTime)
    let endTimeMinute = Alarm.extractMinuteFromTimeDouble(alarmTimeDouble: endTime)
    cell.endTimeLabel.text = formatTime(hour: endTimeHour, minute: endTimeMinute)

    guard let notificationUuids = self.getNotificationUuidsFromAlarmMO(alarmMO: alarmMO) else {
        os_log("Could not get notificationUuids from AlarmMO in tableView(cellForRowAt:) in AlarmTableViewController.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return cell
    }
    os_log("----- notificationUuids: -----", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    for uuid in notificationUuids {
        os_log("uuid: %@", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug, uuid)
    }

    return cell

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if (editingStyle == .delete) {

        guard let alarm = self.alarms[safe: indexPath.row] else {
            os_log("Could not get alarm from its indexPath in AlarmTableViewController.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .default)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            return
        }
        guard let notificationUuids = self.getNotificationUuidsFromAlarmMO(alarmMO: alarm) else {
            os_log("Could not get notificationUuids from AlarmMO in tableView(forRowAt:) in AlarmTableViewController.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            return
        }
        self.removeNotifications(notificationUuids: notificationUuids)
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        managedContext.delete(alarm)
        self.alarms.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        for (index, alarm) in self.alarms.enumerated() {
            let alarmNumber = index + 1
            alarm.setValue(alarmNumber, forKey: "alarmNumber")
        }

        self.saveContext()
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

}

// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func unwindToAlarmList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? AddAlarmViewController, let alarm = sourceViewController.alarm {
        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.alarms.count, section: 0)
        os_log("There are %d notificationUuids attached to the alarm created", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug, alarm.notificationUuids.count)
        saveAlarm(alarmToSave: alarm)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
    }

}

// MARK: Private functions

@objc private func didBecomeActive() {

    deleteOldAlarms {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}

private func deleteOldAlarms(completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    os_log("deleteOldAlarms() called", log: OSLog.default, type: .default)
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    var alarmsToDelete = [AlarmMO]()
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    notificationCenter.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { (requests) in

        alarmsToDelete = self.calculateAlarmsToDelete(requests: requests)
        os_log("Deleting %d alarms", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug, alarmsToDelete.count)
        for alarmMOToDelete in alarmsToDelete {
            guard let notificationUuids = self.getNotificationUuidsFromAlarmMO(alarmMO: alarmMOToDelete) else {
                os_log("Could not get notificationUuids from AlarmMO in deleteOldAlarms() in AlarmTableViewController.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
                return
            }
            self.removeNotifications(notificationUuids: notificationUuids)
            managedContext.delete(alarmMOToDelete)
            self.alarms.removeAll { (alarmMO) -> Bool in
                return alarmMOToDelete == alarmMO
            }
        }
        completionHandler()

    })

}

private func calculateAlarmsToDelete(requests: [UNNotificationRequest]) -> [AlarmMO] {
    var activeNotificationUuids = [String]()
    var alarmsToDelete = [AlarmMO]()
    for request in requests {
        activeNotificationUuids.append(request.identifier)
    }
    for alarm in self.alarms {
        guard let notificationUuids = self.getNotificationUuidsFromAlarmMO(alarmMO: alarm) else {
            os_log("Could not get notificationUuids from AlarmMO in deleteOldAlarms() in AlarmTableViewController.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            return []
        }
        let activeNotificationUuidsSet: Set<String> = Set(activeNotificationUuids)
        let alarmUuidsSet: Set<String> = Set(notificationUuids)
        let union = activeNotificationUuidsSet.intersection(alarmUuidsSet)
        if union.isEmpty {
            alarmsToDelete.append(alarm)
        }
    }
    return alarmsToDelete
}

private func removeNotifications(notificationUuids: [String]) {

    os_log("Removing %d alarm notifications", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug, notificationUuids.count)
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notificationCenter.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: notificationUuids)

}

private func loadAlarms() {

    os_log("loadAlarms() called", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<AlarmMO>(entityName: "Alarm")

    do {
        if self.alarms.count == 0 {
            self.alarms = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            os_log("Loading %d alarms", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug, self.alarms.count)
        } else {
            os_log("Didn't need to load alarms", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch alarms. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}

private func saveAlarm(alarmToSave: Alarm) {

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Alarm", in: managedContext)!
    let alarmMO = AlarmMO(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)

    alarmMO.setValue(alarmToSave.alarmTime, forKeyPath: "alarmTime")
    alarmMO.setValue(alarmToSave.alarmNumber, forKeyPath: "alarmNumber")
    alarmMO.setValue(alarmToSave.alarmIntervalBeginTimeDouble, forKeyPath: "startTimeInterval")
    alarmMO.setValue(alarmToSave.alarmIntervalEndTimeDouble, forKeyPath: "endTimeInterval")
    alarmMO.setValue(alarmToSave.recurrence.hashValue, forKeyPath: "recurrence")
    alarmMO.setValue(alarmToSave.notificationUuids, forKeyPath: "notificationUuids")

    if managedContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            self.alarms.append(alarmMO)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save alarm to CoreData. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    } else {
        os_log("No changes to the context to save", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    }

}

private func getNotificationUuidsFromAlarmMO(alarmMO: AlarmMO) -> [String]? {

    guard let notificationUuids = alarmMO.value(forKey: "notificationUuids") as! [String]? else {
        os_log("Found nil when attempting to unwrap notificationUuids in getNotificationUuidsFromAlarmMO() in AlarmTableViewController.swift, returning nil",
               log: OSLog.default, type: .default)
        return nil
    }
    return notificationUuids

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be simplest if this method *always* runs asynchronously and *always* calls a completion handler. So, your calling code would hand this method a completion handler as it calls it, and stop. Later this method would call the caller back on the completion handler, thus notifying it that we created some notifications. A possible sketch:

```
private func createNotifications(dateComponents: DateComponents, completion: (Int) -> Void) {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.getPendingNotificationRequests { (notifications) in
        switch (recurrence) { 
            // this is wrong, you should not be looking outside this method for the recurrence value...
            // ... but it's just a sketch
            case .today:
                createNotification(for: dateComponents)
                completion(1)
            case .tomorrow:
                createNotification(for: day(after: dateComponents))
                completion(1)
            case .daily:
                // ... decide whether to create the notifications or not ...
                // ... and create however many you decide to ...
                let howManyWeCreated = // however many we created
                completion(howManyWeCreated)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this work with my code in AlarmTableViewController, which is the main VC, and which mainly stores the alarm to Core Data? Do I need to stop storing the alarm in Core Data in my AlarmTableViewController file and instead do it inside this completion handler? Or should I instead maybe have some public method in the AlarmTableViewController file that saves to Core Data that gets called as the completion method instead of a completion handler?

Comment: BTW, I've updated my question to have all of the relevant code from AlarmTableViewController.

Comment: None of the "relevant code" is relevant. The only thing that matters is how you call `createNotifications`, and you didn't show that.

Comment: I call createNotifications() at the very end of my Alarm.init() method, which does some initialization of the time of the alarm and then formats the dateComponents passed into createNotifications(). All of the code that deals with Core Data and the created Alarm is in AlarmTableViewController above.